# How to include tpl files in name_of_module_ouput function in WHMCS

Tags: php, whmcs

Need to know how to include tpl files and assign value to those tpl files.In this example

```
function addonexample_output($vars) {   
    $modulelink = $vars['modulelink'];
    $version = $vars['version'];
    $option1 = $vars['option1'];
    $option2 = $vars['option2'];
    $option3 = $vars['option3'];
    $option4 = $vars['option4'];
    $option5 = $vars['option5'];
    $LANG = $vars['_lang'];

    echo '<p>'.$LANG['intro'].'</p>
<p>'.$LANG['description'].'</p>
<p>'.$LANG['documentation'].'</p>';

}
```

output is echo, but I need to include tpl files and assign values from _output function.

Comment: You should check the following documentation: http://docs.whmcs.com/Order_Form_Templates . Does it help?

Comment: Thanks for reply but this is an article for order forms tpl files, I need how to include tpl files when we create addon module inside _output function.

Answer (score 1):

Including .tpl files is used as a sentence like this:

```
{include file="$template/tplfileuneed.tpl" title=$LANG.knowledgebasecategories}
```

This only works on the template folder.

Good luck!